# A homework problem on probability theory

Tags: probability

I just can't figure how to approach this:
If **A** and **B** are two events such that $P(A \cup B)$= 5/6, $P(A\cap B)$ =1/3, then which one of the following is correct?
(a) A and B are independent, (b) A and B' are independent, (c) A' and B are independent or (d) A and B are dependent.The answer says: d(that they are dependent).

Comment: how about for independent events P(A n B) = P(A)P(B) and you also have P(A u B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A n B) so you can create a quadratic equation to see what P(A) and P(B) could be for independent events

Comment: @Cato, I don't think that would be of any good, because we are working with an assumption and believing it to be true all the time. We are required to comment not to solve,right?

Comment: I was trying to prove (d) they are dependant, however I've proved they don't have to be dependant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: You're looking to show that $P(A | B) = P(A)$. You know that $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$, and $P(A \cap B) = P(B) P(A|B)$.

Comment: would you be able to expand on any of that?  I've found that A and B could be independent, but also dependent.  I found values that work for A and B independent, but of course alternatively A could still be totally contained in B.

Answer (score 2):

Let $P(A\cap B^c)=x,\ P(B\cap A^c)=y.$ since
$$
\frac{5}{6}=P(A\cup B)=P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B^c)+P(B\cap A^c)=\frac{1}{3}+x+y,
$$
we obtain $x+y=1/2$, and hence $y=1/2-x$.

Hence we can rewrite $P(A)=x+1/3$ and $P(B)=5/6-x.$ We observe that
$$
P(A)P(B)=(x+\frac{1}{3})(\frac{5}{6}-x)=-(x-\frac{1}{4})^2+\frac{19}{72} \leq \frac{19}{72}<\frac{24}{72}=\frac{1}{3}=P(A\cap B).
$$
Therefore, $A$ and $B$ is not independent.

Answer (score 0):

a = P(A)
b = P(B)

P(A U B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A n B)

P(A) + P(B) = P(A U B) + P(A n B) = 5/6 + 1/3 = 7/6

a + b = 7/6

assumption of independence
P(A n B) = P(A)P(B) = ab = 1/3

we have 2 equations

a + b = 7/6
ab = 1/3

a(7/6 - a) = 1/3

3a^2 - 7a / 2 + 1 = 0

a = 2/3 
b = 1/2   (or other way around, no loss of generality with that0

P(A) = 2/3

P(B) = 1/2

here with the values found

P(A|B) = P(A n B) / P(B) = (1 / 3 ) / (1 / 2) = 2 / 3 = P(A)

I don't see why the info given means they have to be dependent